# Mul(Multiplication) in x64 and in x32 assembly

Tags: binary-analysis, x86, malware, amd64

I'm completely new in malware reverse engineering. I'm stuck in a confusion that,

I studied that in x32, mul instruction multiplies the source with eax register and store the result as 64 bit value across two registers i.e. EDX:EAX. EDX stores most significant bit of 32 bits of operation and EAX do the same. So, my question is what happens in x64? how the values are stored in RAX:RDX after multiplication. I also ping the Google but did'nt understand much. I hope you all will respond.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/39/c5/325462-sdm-vol-1-2abcd-3abcd.pdf) Page 1320

The result is stored in register AX, register pair DX:AX, or register pair EDX:EAX (depending on the operand size),
with the high-order bits of the product contained in register AH, DX, or EDX, respectively. If the high-order bits of
the product are 0, the CF and OF flags are cleared; otherwise, the flags are set.
In 64-bit mode, the instruction’s default operation size is 32 bits. Use of the REX.R prefix permits access to addi-
tional registers (R8-R15). Use of the REX.W prefix promotes operation to 64 bits.
See the summary chart at the beginning of this section for encoding data and limits.

[image: mul table]

It can be seen with this sequence of instructions

```
mov rdx, 0x1234567890abcdef
mov rax, 0x100
mul rdx
```

After the last instruction

```
$rax   : 0x34567890abcdef00
$rdx   : 0x12
```

`RDX` has the upper 64 bits as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your time, iI'll also see the documentation.

Comment: @AdilNehal If this answer works, mark as solved by accepting.